# how to push Google Analytics data into mysql tables

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-api

I see many tutos to download GA data to a google spreadsheet and refresh it automatically
but none to export data into mysql table(s) 
Is it possible ?
If yes where can i find tutos or a freelancer with skills on this subject 
If yes is it possible to store the data of several UA in the same table ?
Thx

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do that with the [Google Analytics core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) and you can use [their query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to see what data you can pull from it.

Also here is all their [libraries and sample code](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries) that you can use as a tutorial. As far as hiring someone, I would check out the job board here or odesk.com.

Comment: Thx Nico for your suggestion, i posted two jobs on Odesk (wordpress on Google Cloud and how to download data from GA to Mysql) with no response... can we contact u ?

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to play around with code and development, just go ahead and use [Analytics Canvas](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/) that provides easy data import via API from Google Analytics, which you can then easily export to SQL / MySQL / any other database. All using simple and intuitive graphic interface.