# Google Analytics Reporting API vs Query Parameters

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, query-string, google-reporting-api

I am trying to build a centralized dashboard to display information from google analytics. I have researched about reporting API which helps in embedding charts directly form analytics dashboard and also on query parameters to store analytics data in local database such as MySQL. I wanted to know which would be easy to implement and which is more effective. I have more than 300 websites which are monitored on analytics through a single account, So the data is going to be huge. I t would be great if anyone could post a code snippet to access data from analytics and store it in the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Google Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/), it is the updated version after [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference). The [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) can help you to identify what data to extract.

There is also another alternative if you want easier data import/export. This [Analytics Canvas](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/) can do the job.

For reference, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151771/how-to-push-google-analytics-data-into-mysql-tables).